# Need help ISPConfig 3 Configuration/Setup

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I recently installed ISPConfig 3 on my server and I'm a little lost in it as to how to configure the DNS zones and name servers and link them up to the websites, etc anyone using ISPConfig 3 can you please guide me on how to do it

Also if you have any basic documentation or help on how to work around it will be big help there is documentation on ISPConfig 2 but nothing on 3 and they are totally different so I'm totally confused on where to begin please help!

PS: ([This is the guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.3-x86_64-ispconfig-3) I used to set it up)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ISPConfig installed, you have already a working nameserver.

At your domain registry, enter the domain of your ISPConfig server as namesever and the external IP of your ISPConfig server as IP of your nameserver.

Then go to the ISPConfig controlpanel and add the domains in the DNS-Manager.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to add domains to ispconfig. At first, go to DNS -> Add new DNS zone with wizard.

Fill the fields there. Use the ip address as server's ip address and nsrecords as ns1.ispconfig_domain & ns2.ispconfig_domain (you need to add *.ispconfig_domain in the domain control panel of your ispconfig server).

Then add a new website from site page.

Note that propogation of NS record can take 1-2 days.